# Unequally weighted lottery hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, weighted-sampling

I have a question in which I am given the expected results for a weighted lottery in conditional probabilities (based on gender and race different tickets in the lottery), I also have the actual conditional probabilities calculated from the lottery data. How would i conduct a hypothesis test to see if the lottery is rigged or not?